# Conditionally Filtering in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to conditionally add `filter` arguments to a query in the SQL Alchemy ORM?

For example imagine, I have the following:

```
q = session.query(X)
if a:
 q.filter(X.y == 'a')
elif b:
 q.filter(X.y == 'a', X.z == 'b')
elif c:
 q.filter(X.y == 'a', X.p == 'd')
```

Is there a way to say just add

`X.z == 'b'` if `b`

without having to readd `(X.y == 'a')` in every filter.

It seems that I could do

`q.filter(X.y == 'a').filter(X.y == 'b')`

but this changes the query that is being performed.

Answer (score 70):

Try collecting your queries into a list, and then use the `*` operator when you call `filter`:

```
queries = [X.y == 'a']
if b:
    queries.append(X.z == 'b')
q.filter(*queries)
```

And BTW I don't understand why you think chaining two `filter`s would change your query, it would correspond to `X.y = a AND X.z = b` like when you use `filter(X.y == 'a', X.z == 'b')`.

Comment: This is PERFECT!  I'm using this * operator to conditionally pass in multiple criteria into an or_ function