# what is the meaning of * on python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the next queries.

```
item = [item.export_simple()
            for item in session.query(Item)
                               .filter(and_(
                                       Item.companyId == company_id,
                                       or_(
                                           True if search == "" else None,
                                           or_(*[Item.name.like('%{0}%'.format(s)) for s in words]),
                                           or_(*[Item.code.like('%{0}%'.format(s)) for s in words])
                                            ))).order_by(Item.name)]
```

and this one.

```
if type == "code":
            src = [Item.code.like('%{0}%'.format(s)) for s in words]
        elif type == "name":
            src = [Item.name.like('%{0}%'.format(s)) for s in words]

 session.query(Item)
                    .filter(and_(
                        Item.companyId == company_id,
                        Item.typeItem == item_type,
                        or_(
                            True if search == "" else None,
                            or_(*src)
                        )))
```

In both cases i have `*` operator in or_() statement, and both queries work awesome, but i don´t know exactly why. 
This is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270708/sqlalchemy-filter-query-column-like-any-array) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063860/conditionally-filtering-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't something related to SQLAlchemy. This unpacks a list into comma-separated arguments, and is a brilliant Python feature. It's formally called the "single star" operator, but it's commonly refered to as the "splat" operator. This:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
something(*a)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
something(1, 2, 3)
```

So, in your first example, it's executing the list comprehension `[Item.name.like('%{0}%'.format(s)) for s in words]` and then unpacking its arguments into the `or_` call.

For more information about this operator, refer to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: For googling purposes, I think it's important to mention that this is often referred to as the splat operator.

Comment: Isn't it also true that when passing a *list or *tuple to something(*a) both get coerced into a tuple inside something()?

Comment: @rp. Can you give a code example please?

Comment: Code showing the coersion is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376674/does-pythons-splat-operator-coerce-lists-into-tuples