# Does Python's splat operator coerce lists into tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, splat

There are several answers to what Python's splat operator does (unpack lists or tuples into separate args inside the called function) but I can't find anything about the interesting side effect of how the splat operator coerces lists to tuples (effectively rendering passing a list with splat as being passed by value, not reference).

So, is it true that Python's splat operator coerces lists into tuples:

```
def test(*arg):
    print(type(arg))
    for a in arg:
        print(a)

lst = ['roger', 'colleen']
print(type(lst))
test(*lst)         

tpl = ('roger', 'colleen')
print(type(tpl))
test(*tpl)
```

It seems to. The code above produces this output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'tuple'>
roger
colleen
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'tuple'>
roger
colleen
```

I'm trying to solidify my knowledge of lists and tuples. I read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) that

> The differences between tuples and lists are,  the tuples cannot be
>   changed unlike lists and tuples use  parentheses, whereas lists use
>   square brackets.

I was at first surprised that calling test() with a list didn't let test() change the list (they aren't immutable). But they are when passed with the splat operator to function because they get coerced to a tuple. Right? I think!

**Update:**
rkersh's comments said something that adds a lot of clarity:

test(*arg) isn't being called with a list, it's being called with the items *in the list*)--and those items are seen by *arg as a tuple.

Comment: In particular, the top answer there says "yes", and links to the section of the official tutorial which says the same.

Comment: The *star expression* `*` unpack the iterable. It doesn't modify it.

Comment: Try this : def test(*arg):
    print(type(*arg))
    for a in arg:
        print(a)

Comment: KART, 'type(*arg)' fails with TypeError: type() takes one or three arguments. (using Python3)

Comment: You aren't calling test() with a list.  You're calling test with the items from a list (the `*` operator unpacks them).  Then, in the test function, arg captures these items in a tuple.

Comment: rkersh--that is a great answer. Calling test' with the items in the list' is well-stated and makes what's happening very clear.