# SQLAlchemy - How can i filter data with kwargs? (And inside or condition)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have conditions list that contains dictionaries such as:

```
conditions = [
    {"language_id": 1, "writer_level_id": 3},
    {"language_id": 2, "writer_level_id": 2},
    {"language_id": 2, "writer_level_id": 3},
    {"language_id": 1, "writer_level_id": 1},
]
```

I'm trying to build a query such as:

```
queries = []
for i in conditions:
    queries.append(
        (
            RelUserWriterLevel.language_id == i["language_id"],
            RelUserWriterLevel.writer_level_id == i["writer_level_id"],
        )
    )
data = data.filter(or_(*queries))
```

It doesn't work because I send tuple in this case. But I want to build an SQL like;

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (language_id = .. and writer_level_id = ..) OR (...);
```

So I don't know how to build AND case inside OR filtering when I need to filter with **kwargs**.

Topics I've researched:

- [SQLALchemy dynamic filter_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885879/sqlalchemy-dynamic-filter-by)
- [Conditionally Filtering in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063860/conditionally-filtering-in-sqlalchemy)

In second topic, the solution works for only one case. However, in my problem I need to use it like `queries = [X.y == 'a' AND X.z == 'a', ...]`

And then use it like `filter(or_(*queries))`

I appreciate all your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonders how to solve this issue;

```
queries = (and_(RelUserWriterLevel.language_id==i['language_id'], RelUserWriterLevel.writer_level_id==i['writer_level_id']) for i in conditions)

data = data.filter(or_(*queries))
```

The detailed explanation is here : [How to get rows which match a list of 3-tuples conditions with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140015/how-to-get-rows-which-match-a-list-of-3-tuples-conditions-with-sqlalchemy)

I've solved like this!